# How to make flush() not make loading the page?

Tags: php, flush

Here's the code:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
while (1) {
    echo 'Hi:)<br>';
    sleep(5);
}
```

When I open the site `flush()` makes the page always loading. How can I make the page NOT loading? Like it's been loaded the all stuff

Comment: Dont do it, just use ajax, sse or websockets

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for the advice

Comment: Hi Joe, do you want to simply execute code after output that will not be outputted itself or do you simply want it to not look like it's loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `fastcgi_finish_request();` after `flush`. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php